# $g_n(x)=e^{-x} -(1- \frac{x}{n})^n \mathbb{1}_{x \leq n}$, annulation of $g_n'$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let

- $g_n(x)=e^{-x} -(1- \frac{x}{n})^n \mathbb{1}_{0 \leq x \leq n}$
- We study $g_n(x)$ for $x \geq 0$

We want to prove that there exist an unique $t_n \in ]0,n]$ such that  $g_n'(t_n)=0$

---

My attempt : I derived several times, studied the sign of the derivative.

$
\begin{align*}
g_n(x) &= e^{-x} - \big(1- \frac{x}{n} \big)^n \\
g_n'(x) &= - e^{-x}+ \big(1- \frac{x}{n} \big) ^{n-1} \\
g_n''(x) &= e^{-x}   - \frac{n-1}{n} \big(1- \frac{x}{n} \big) ^{n-2}  \\
\end{align*}
$

$\begin{align*}
g_n'(x) &\geq - e^{-x} + 1 - \frac{n-1}{n}x \\
            &\geq - e^{-x} + \frac{x}{n} \ := \psi(n)\\
\psi'(n)&= e^{-x} + \frac{1}{n}  \geq 0\\
\psi(0)&=-1 \\
\psi(n)&= - e^{-n} + 1 >0\\
 \end{align*}
$

$
\begin{align*}
g_n'(x) &\geq 0 \iff d(x) \geq 0 \\
d(x)&= x + (n-1) \ln ( 1 - \frac{x}{n}) \\
d'(x)&= 1 + (n-1) ( - \frac{1}{n}) \frac{1}{1- \frac{x}{n} } \\
d'(x)&= 1+ \frac{1-n}{n-x} \\
d'(x)&= \frac{1-x}{n-x} \\
d'(x) &\geq 0 \iff x <1 \\
\end{align*}
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your notations:

When $x \in [0,n)\ $:  $\ g_n'(x)=0 \Longleftrightarrow d(x)=0$

You have shown that $d$ is increasing on $[0,1]$ and decreasing on $[1,n)$.

$d(0)=0\ $ and $\ \lim_{x\rightarrow n} d(x)=-\infty$.

It's easy to conclude, then.

Comment: Are my calculation corrects ? Is there a better method ?

Comment: It's false that $g_n' \geqslant \psi$ (with your notations). It's useless to search $g_n''$. I think that the best method is to study $d$.