# $e^{-x}\mathbb{1}_{x \geq 0} -(1- \frac{x}{n})^n \mathbb{1}_{ 0 \leq x \leq n}$ : max

Tags: real-analysis

- Let  $g_n(x)=e^{-x}\mathbb{1}_{x \geq 0} -(1- \frac{x}{n})^n \mathbb{1}_{ 0 \leq x \leq n}$
- I want to show that  $\max\limits_{ x<n} g_n(x) < \frac{1}{ne}$

---

My attempt :
I have proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800569/g-nx-e-x-1-fracxnn-mathbb1-x-leq-n-annulation-of-g-n) that $g_n$ admits a maximum.

$\begin{align*}
0&=g_n'(t_n) \\
0&= -e^{-t_n} - (1- \frac{t_n}{n})^{n-1} \\ 
e^{-t_n} &= (1- \frac{t_n}{n})^{n-1} \\
g_n(t_n)&=e^{-t_n} - (1- \frac{x}{n})^{n}) \\
g_n(t_n)&=e^{-t_n} -e^{-t_n} (1- \frac{t_n}{n}) \\
g_n(t_n)&=e^{-t_n}(1- 1 + \frac{t_n}{n}) \\
g_n(t_n)&=e^{-t_n}\frac{t_n}{n}\\
\psi(u)&:=u e^{-u} \\
\psi'(u)&=e^{-u} (1-u) <0\\
\psi(u) &< e^{-1} \\
g_n(t_n) &< \frac{1}{en}\\
\end{align*}
$

$1<t_n<n$

Comment: What do you know about the point $x_n$ where $g_n$ attains its maximum?

Comment: $1< x_n <n$  that is all

Comment: You know more. At a point where a differentiable function attains an extremum ...

Comment: Its derivative equals zero, but can I do an expansion ?

Comment: And what does $g_n'(x) = 0$ say?

Comment: $- x_n = (n-1) \ln(1 - \frac{x_n}{n} ) $  There an inequality $\ln(1+u) <u$

Comment: It's better to not take the logarithm here. We have $\bigl(1 - \frac{x_n}{n}\bigr)^{n-1} = e^{-x_n}$. Now if you insert that into the definition of $g_n$, what do you get?

Comment: $g_n(x_n)=( 1 - \frac{x_n}{n})^{n-1} -( 1 - \frac{x_n}{n})^{n-1})^n=  ( 1 - \frac{x_n}{n})( 1- 1+ \frac{x_n}{n} )$ and I can minimize $\psi(u) = (1-u)u$ for $0<u<1$

Comment: IMO it's more convenient to make the replacement in the other term.

Comment: $g_n(x_n)= e^{-x_n} - e^{-x_n} (1- \frac{x_n}{n} ) = e^{-x_n} \frac{x_n}{n}$

Comment: Yep. And what do you know about the function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{n}\cdot xe^{-x}$?

Comment: I am looking for a bound, I assume that I shall find $xe^{-x} < e^{-1}$ for $1<x<n$

Comment: $\psi(x)= x e^{-x}$ sp $\psi'(x)=e^{-x} (1-x) <0$ so $\psi$ is decreasing. $ \psi(1)=e^{-1}$

Comment: Indeed. Finding where $xe^{-x}$ attains its maximum, and determining that maximum is straightforward, and your desired conclusion drops out.

Comment: Thanks so much !